# Android - convert audio to .mp3

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, encode

I am trying to record audio ( using MediaRecorder ) and send it to a server in .mp3 format.
I have checked the web for solutions to converting any of the audio file formats received from MediaRecorder to .mp3 format, but I could not find any adequate solution ( also tried tritonus, but did not manage to use it ).

Please, can you give me a code sample or a link to a tutorial that can show me how to convert audio to .mp3 on the Android platform using standard Java code ( not C + NDK or anything ).

This is a show stopper for me, so I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Sabin